# Update/fill embedded Excel table on mouse click in Powerpoint slideshow

Tags: excel, vba, powerpoint, office-2016

I need to create simple one-slide Powerpoint slideshow with one table or chart used as scoreboard.

- During announcement of results I need to control showing of results for example by mouse clicks like in normal slideshow.
- Also I need to control order of showing results (I mean team with the smallest amount of points need to be shown first etc.)
- I need to dynamically sort table when values changes.

I already done third point (auto sorting table when values in ´SUM´ column changes). I created Excel sheet with my desired table and applied below code for auto sorting table.

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Calculate()
    On Error Resume Next

    Range("A3:H8").Sort Key1:=Range("H3:H8"), _
        Order1:=xlDescending, Header:=xlNo, _
        OrderCustom:=1, MatchCase:=False, _
        Orientation:=xlTopToBottom
End Sub
```

I added this table by link using paste special option into powerpoint slide and when I update data in Excel, data in powerpoint also changes (but also it does not work every time, sometimes I need to right click on table in powerpoint and actualize connection). But when I run slideshow, this does not work.

Here is example of table:

```
--------------------------------------------------------
| Team | Round 1 | Round 2 | Round 3 | Round 4 | Total |
--------------------------------------------------------
|  T1  |    2    |    3    |         |         |   5   |
--------------------------------------------------------
|  T3  |    3    |    1    |         |         |   4   |
--------------------------------------------------------
|  T2  |    0    |    3    |         |         |   3   |
--------------------------------------------------------
```

Then in `Round 3` this was results:

```
------------------
| Team | Round 3 | 
------------------
|  T1  |    1    |
------------------
|  T3  |    3    |
------------------
|  T2  |    5    |
------------------
```

And I want to show:

1. 1 point for `T1` in column `Round 3` and update `Total` to 6.
2. 3 points for `T3` in column `Round 3`, update `Total` to 7 and finally sort rows in table by `Total` column descending so `T3` will be first, `T1` second, and `T2` will remain at third place.
3. 5 points for `T2` in column `Round 3`, update `Total` to 8 and sort rows in table so `T2` = first, `T3` = second and `T1` will be last.

Best solution will be that I will prefill the column `Round 3` before score announcement presentation and then during presentation I will just click the mouse button and the information will popup. I mean after first click point 1 will execute, after second click point 2 will execute, etc.

Is it possible to update data in table during presentation?
Can I prefill table with data, choose order of showing and control showing of them by mouse click?

Comment: Finally I just added chart from excel into powerpoint with link. Than I started slideshow on projector, and on laptop monitor I had opened excel where I inserted values into table. Chart was imeditially edited when I edited table and also linked chart in powerpoint slideshow was edited too.

Answer (score 0):

In reference to [here](https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/office/forum/office_2010-powerpoint/how-to-update-powerpoint-2010-slides-automatically/ba395680-f9dc-4673-8bac-8a5637047fc0), this is a code that updates the table each time you start the presentation:

```
 Sub OnSlideShowPageChange(ByVal objWindow As SlideShowWindow)
   If objWindow.View.CurrentShowPosition = _
                 objWindow.Presentation.SlideShowSettings.StartingSlide Then
     'Put your update code here
   End If
 End Sub
```

**You can also add a button to your slide which runs the update macro**. I also think it can be linked to "click" (instead of a button) which is more convenient but am not sure.

Comment: Haven´t tried yet but it is not exactly what I want. I will maybe update data in table during slideshow but i need to change table in excel simultaneously during presentation, which is not very comfortable.

Comment: It's not exactly clear to me what you want to do. You want to update the table within ppt instead of excel? You can add the `actualization of link` to your code. As I said adding a Button using `Developer` tab can be an answer to your need. Moreover, You can set a timer, which I don't recommend, for updating the table.

Comment: I updated my question. Hope it will be now better understandable.

Comment: Finally it worked just fine when I just added linked chart from excel to powerpoint. Only one think was that it doesn´t work when I closed excel and powerpoint. When I opened it again I needed to paste (with link) chart with data from that table into powerpoint slideshow and it worked just fine.

Comment: @Gondil Read answer to this question: https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/msoffice/forum/msoffice_powerpoint-mso_other/error-with-excel-objects-in-powerpoint-2010/cb7cd647-8865-4942-a63a-191c7fe1f9f1